# Match files that have a 0000 in the filename on a certain position

Tags: regex, bash

I have hundreds of files like this:

```
201670000_FOR1.xml
201670000_GAL0.xml
201670000_GAL1.xml
20184301_2.xml
20184301_3.xml
20184301_4.xml
```

I need to match all the files that have a `0000` on position 6-9. The first 3 files should match, the bottom 3 not. I tried:

```
find -E . -regex '/^.{6}0000*/' | wc -l
```

but it yields zero results. How would the correct regex look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `find` regex:

```
find -E . -regex '.*/.{5}0{4}.*'
```

```
./201670000_GAL0.xml
./201670000_FOR1.xml
./201670000_GAL1.xml
```

**Regex Details:**

- `.*` matches part of filename before `/`
- `.{5}` matches first 5 characters after `/`
- Then we match 4 zeroes using `0{4}`
- Finally `.*` for remaining characters.

You can also **avoid** regex by using this **glob pattern**:

```
find . -name '?????0000*'
```

Answer (score 1):

The slashes cannot be part of a file name. Take them out. (Some tools do require slashes as delimiters around regexes but `find` is definitely not one of them.)

Your examples all have five characters, not six, before the zeros, and `0*` matches only zeros, not a zero followed by anything (that would be `0.*`) so you probably want `^.{5}0{4}.*`

More economically and succinctly,

```
wc -l ?????0000*
```

matches all files with this pattern in the current directory, and

```
wc -l **/?????0000*
```

in many shells examines all subdirectories recursively (but `**` is not properly portable to POSIX `sh`).

It's not clear from your question whether you want to examine subdirectories, but `find` always examines subdirectories, too, unless you specifically tell it not to. On a tree with many subdirectories, this can make a significant difference in performance.

Comment: Pathologically, PHP has both quotes and slash delimiters around regexes, I hear.